# how to extend Virtual Box harddrive?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, disk-space, vdi

I run WinXP SP3 on my Virtual Box (3.2.10) under OSX  10.6.2 and the harddrive of the virtual box is getting too small.

Can I

- extend exiting hdd somehow?
- create new Virtual Box from a running computer? (Virtual Box in my case?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process using only vboxmanage(which you already have if you have vbox) to make a new larger image and cloning the data across os here: http://alittletothewright.com/index.php/2009/11/expanding-virtualbox-dynamic-vdis/.  you can then use the windows partitioning tools to expand the partitions.

Comment: I like your solution better, more elegant. Thank you.

Comment: no problem...thx for the check

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can do to increase the size of your disk (like booting GParted and increasing the partition size) but I'd recommend the following:

1. Create a new disk, larger than the current one and dynamically expending
2. Mount the new disk on your VM
3. Download [EASUS Disk Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/) 2.3 ISO (free)
4. Boot your VM from Disc Copy ISO
5. Copy the old disk to the new one
6. "Eject" the ISO and mark the new disk as your boot disk - you now have a larger disk containing the contenst of the old one.

If your VM has a Windows OS, it may be that you now have 2 partitions on the new disk. You can use the Windows interface or DiskPArt to merge them, if you'd like.

Comment: Guess it's not nice enough :)

Comment: I think the check was switched because I didn't require additional tools.  That way it works in more isolated environments or in instances when you don't have the time to download an ISO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make it larger after making it, but when making a new virtual drive, you can set it as "Dynamically expanding" so it will get larger as it fills up. So you might be able to make a new VM with a Dynamically expanding drive and transfer your data over.

Comment: I know about Dynamically expanding drives but I was given vdi and I do not want to reinstall the whole virtual box to have the same programs there.